# JWT Token doesn't expire after a certain time

Tags: express, jwt, express-jwt

Why my jwt token doesn't expire after 1 hour?

I've noticed that it doesn't expire when I forgot to logout my account in my admin panel that I created in vuejs with vuex.

here is my API that I created in ExpressJS using bcrypt and express-jwt for token.

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
let sql = "SELECT * FROM AUTHENTICATION WHERE email = ?";
myDB.query(sql, [req.body.email, req.body.password], function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        if (!results) {
            res.status(404).send('No user found.')
        } else {
            try {
                let passwordMatched = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, results[0].password);
                if (passwordMatched) {
                    // Passwords match
                    let token = jwt.sign({ id: results.id }, config.secret, {
                        expiresIn: '1h'
                    });
                    res.status(200).send({ auth: true, token: token, user: results });
                } else {
                    //Password doesn't match
                    return res.status(401).send({ auth: false, token: null });
                }
            } catch (error) {
                res.send({ Success: false })
            }
        }
    }
})
});
```

here's my login in vuex where I received the token from my backend.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const state = {
    status: '',
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
    user: {}
};
const getters = {
    isLoggedIn: state => !!state.token,
    authStatus: state => state.status,
};

const mutations = {
    auth_request(state) {
        state.status = 'loading'
    },
    auth_success(state, token, user) {
        state.status = 'success'
        state.token = token
        state.user = user
    },
    auth_error(state) {
        state.status = 'error'
    },
    logout(state) {
        state.status = ''
        state.token = ''
    },
};
const actions = {
    login({ commit }, user) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            commit('auth_request')
            axios({ url: 'http://localhost:9001/login/login', data: user, method: 'POST' })
                .then(resp => {
                    const token = resp.data.token
                    const user = resp.data.user
                    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
                    // Add the following line:
                    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
                    commit('auth_success', token, user)
                    resolve(resp)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    commit('auth_error')
                    localStorage.removeItem('token')
                    reject(err)
                })
        })
    }
};
```

**EDIT:** Added vuejs code for login

thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Can you show us your Vue code? Are you actually verifying the token periodically, or just once when you log in? JWT expiration doesn't have anything to do with your authentication system, it just means that the token should no longer be considered valid if you try to verify it too long (in this case more than one hour) after it was created.

Answer (score 0):

Your JWT token is just an encoded + signed JSON with relevant fields such as `expiresIn`, `iat`.

While it may contain the `expiresIn` field, it does not mean that the backend server will honour it.

Logic needs to be written in the backend server to parse the timestamp, do comparison with the current time to determine whether it has expired. If it is expired, the backend should return a response code of `401 Unauthorized` to tell the frontend (your Vue client) that the token is no longer valid.

What you can do is to put the expiry-checking logic in a middleware to look into the request headers' Authorization field.